# Flattening Transparencies - Gimp, Scribus, and DriveThruRPG

Tags: pdf, printing, gimp, scribus

I used Scribus to create a black and white PDF, including images prepared with Gimp.  I submitted the PDF to DriveThruRPG for their print on demand service and it was initially rejected by their printer (Lightning Source).  This was the feedback from DriveThruRPG:

> the interior file had some PDF/X compliance issues. They ran it
> through preflight, flattening transparencies, and the resulting file
> worked.

For next time, how do I fix this problem on my end?  Here is the workflow that I used:

- I received images from various sources, opened them in Gimp, converted them to grayscale, and saved them in EPS format.  None of the images contained any transparency that I am aware of.  Most of the images consisted of black line art on a white background.
- In Scribus I created a document, set the Color to Grayscale, laid out the text, imported the EPS images that I had created with Gimp, and exported the document with Compatibility set to PDF/X-1a.

What would it mean to "flatten transparencies" and at what point in the process would I do that?  In Gimp?  In Scribus?

**Edit**:

Okay I see that GIMP has a Flatten Image command which removes the alpha channel.  Should I try running that on all of the images before saving them in EPS format?

Could Scribus also be introducing transparency into the PDF somewhere?  At this link... [Is there a way to flatten a .pdf image from the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162922/is-there-a-way-to-flatten-a-pdf-image-from-the-command-line) ...I see this command:

```
pdf2ps orig.pdf - | ps2pdf - flattened.pdf
```

Should I also run that on the PDF before sending it to the printer?